# fatal error : linux/interrupt.h : no such file or directory

Tags: linux-kernel, error-handling, interrupt, pthreads, signal-messenger

I am developing code for interrupt. When I am including `#include <linux/interrupt.h>`, I get

```
fatal error : linux/interrupt.h no such file or directory
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve this error?

When instead I am including that header file I'll get one more error. Finally I'll get linux/compiler.h error.

But all these files are present in `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-151/include/linux/`

Can you please help me find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Where appear to be words missing form your question. And what is the meaning of the word “ill” in this context? (if it is an abbreviation then use the full word).

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your question to include the missing words and fix the capitalization / punctuation where possible. Currently your question is quite unclear because it seems to be missing a few things and is hard to read. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

A `#include <linux/interrupt.h>` looks headers by default in `/usr/include`. This time, it would look for `/usr/include/linux/interrupt.h`. This file does not exist, because in Linux, by default you are developing a user space application. These have very limited access to any system-wide interrupts.

The file in your `/usr/src/linux*/include/linux`, is a kernel header. It is not usable by user-space apps. It is usable only for kernel modules.

In short, `/usr/include/linux` contains the headers *for the user-space processes to deal with the kernel API*. While the `/path-to-kernel-source/include/linux` contains the internal header files used by the kernel. Linux kernel developers face them mostly if he develops kernel modules.

If you are doing a user space development, you should interact with CPU interrupts very differently. Best if you don't play with interrupts et al, or you are doing it with a kernel module.

If you are doing a linux kernel (kernel module) development, you should use very different gcc flags (they will make the common `/usr/include` unreachable).